# If the flop is 779. one player has 99 and another has 79. who wins so far

Tags: texas-hold-em

If the flop is 779. one player has 99 another player has 79. who wins so far

Comment: Player two only has 1/990 chance of winning the pot

Answer (score 2):

Player 1 best hand is a fullhouse 999 77
Player 2 best hand is a fullhouse 777 99

Player 1 has an higher ranked fullhouse and thus win the hand (if no 7 on turn and river).